# efficiently method for generating a sequence

Tags: performance-tuning, integer-sequence

The sequence is defined as $a(1)=1,a(n)=a(n-1)+a\left(\left\lfloor \log _2(n)\right\rfloor \right)$

A natural way do this is

```
ClearAll[a];
a[1] = 1;
a[n_] := a[n] = a[n - 1] + a[Floor@Log2@N@n];
Table[a[i], {i, 1, 2^20}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It's not very quickly enough. I think there is a iteration solution using `Nest` or `Fold`,but I can't get it.

Comment: You can get a slight improvement by using `BitLength@n-1` instead of `Floor@Log2@N@n`

Comment: Do you need to generate the whole sequence from 1 to some N, or do you want a faster way to generate results for some large distinct arguments?

Comment: @ciao I need  to generate the whole sequence from 1 to N.

Comment: @mathe - then see my answer.

Comment: @mathe - did answer address issue ?

Comment: @ciao Solved, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be much *much* faster:

```
a3[1]={1};
a3[m_] := Module[{t = 2^Range[Floor[Log2[m]]], a},

   a[1] = 1;
   a[n_] := a[n] = a[n - 1] + a[Floor[Log2[n]]];

   t[[-1]] = m - Tr[Most@t] - 1;
   Accumulate@Prepend[Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {a /@ Range[Length@t], t}], 1]];
```

Using:

```
a3[X]
```

will produce the same output as

```
Table[a[i], {i, 1, X}]
```